# Create thumbs on the fly vs after upload

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Just wondering what is better:

**Create thumbs on the fly:**

- [+] easy to create numerous thumb sizes
- [+] easy to maintenance
- [-] <strike>wasting cpu by sending images thru PHP</strike>

**Create thumbs after user upload:**

- [+] saving server cpu
- [-] very painful to maintenance and painful to new add thumb size
- [-] maybe the thumbs are never shown.

Any suggestions? Should i really worry about CPU?
Let's say I have thousands of images, and every image needs thumb in 5+ different sizes. Maybe even more sizes in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [-] wasting cpu by sending images thru PHP

You don't have to generate the same image *again and again on each request!*
Generate the image the first time it's requested, then put it in a place where it will be served by the web server the next time. A simple implementation for this using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ generateImage.php?image=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

after user upload:
[-] i don't know your project, but maybe the thumbs are never shown. So the server don't need to render the thumbs.

i generate the thumbs on the fly